# Azure .vhd file downloading is larger than hd image size?

Tags: azure, vhd

I created a **.vhd** image and downloading through the portal using Edge.

The **.vhd** file in the portal shows it's 127gb (which is the size of the hard drive on the VM).

The actual usage is 33gb - as shown below. The problem is, other than being very slow to download, it's currently showing 40gb downloaded and is still continuing.

Can anyone tell me why this is or suggest a good, quick, alternative to downloading?!
Thanks - Rob

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      131045924 32279488  93405860  26% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             3563804        8   3563796   1% /dev
tmpfs             713764      380    713384   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             3568800        0   3568800   0% /run/shm
none              102400        0    102400   0% /run/user
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of the file is 127GB as you mentioned. So when you directly download via browser, it will always download the entire file i.e. 127GB and not the data that is currently being occupied as the browser doesn't know how much full your VHD is.

What you need to do is use the tools which support `Sparse Download`. In this method, first the tool identifies the occupied bytes (or rather occupied pages as it is a Page Blob) and downloads only those bytes.

On Windows, you can use `AzCopy` tool. It supports sparse download. On Mac/Linux platform, try downloading the VHD via `CLI tools`. Though I have not used it but my guess is that it also supports sparse download.

You may find this blog post from Azure Storage Team on how to efficiently upload/download Page Blobs: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/04/10/using-windows-azure-page-blobs-and-how-to-efficiently-upload-and-download-page-blobs/.